# Evaluate function with parameters stored in an environment

Tags: r

Say I have this function

```
myfun <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3)a * b * c
```

I also have an environment where some of the arguments a,b,c are stored, but I don't know which ones (if any).

For example,

```
e <- new.env()
assign("a", 10, envir=e)
```

Now I can use `do.call` to use `a` from the `e` environment to evaluate `myfun` :

```
do.call(myfun, list(quote(a)), envir=e)
```

My question is, what if I don't know which possible arguments are actually stored in the `e` environment? I can get the listing as `ls(envir=e)` , but I have been unable to use this in a `do.call` statement.

For the moment, assume that `e` never contain objects that are not possible arguments to `myfun` (i.e. it can only contain a,b or c).

Comment: What do you want to do if the environment doesn't contain all values of a, b, and c? Use the function defaults?

Comment: Yes, use the defaults - the answer below does actually allow for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can coerce your environment to a list, and then use `do.call`

```
do.call(myfun, as.list(e))
# [1] 60
```